# Hexagon into 12 identical hexagons

Tags: geometry, puzzle, tiling

Puzzle: Divide a regular hexagon into 12 identical non-convex hexagons.

I found this at [Jaap Scherphuis' Tiling Applet](http://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/), and it looks new to me.  Are there any solutions other than the one answer there?

Comment: Related problem -- divide a regular pentagon into 30 identical pieces. Michael Reid solved this one, but I've misplaced his solution.

Comment: That applet has hundreds of tilings! Please tell us how to navigate to your hexagonal tiling.

Comment: TonyK -- go to hexagon tilings, non-convex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Comment: LOL. The SE system thinks this post is of _very_ low quality, $(-6)$, crazy system !

Comment: I mean...solution is not even presented using a custom tikz script with colorblind safe colors. Clearly needs to be downvoted /s